I am getting 404 error in postman with post method in laravel
I used post method in laravel still getting error 404.
Here is my code:
TaskController.php
 public function changeStatus(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $task = Task::find($id);
            if (!$task) {
                return Helper::error(__('messages.task_not_found'), 404);
            }
            $input = $request->all();
            $validator = Validator::make($input, [
                'status' => 'required|boolean'
            ]);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return Helper::error($validator->errors()->first(), 422);
            }
            $task->status = $input['status'];
            $task->save();
            DB::commit();
            return Helper::success(__('messages.task_status_updated'), new someDetailResource($task), 200);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            report($th);
            DB::rollBack();
            return Helper::error(__('messages.something_went_wrong'), 500);
        }
    }

api.php
Route::prefix('task')->controller(TaskController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::post('changeStatus/{id}', 'changeStatus');
});

In Postman
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task/changeStatus/6
I am getting 404 error in Postman.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks for considering my request.
I have double verified. All things are correct.

Try php artisan route:list, this should return your route. Otherwise there is a problem with route definition.

Worth to check your route:list indeed. But also, if there is no task with id 6, you manually return a status code 404..

Does this work better when calling the route in the browser (such that Postman is not involved)?

First check if your route is registered or not, to check you can use the following command in the terminal. This command will display all the registered routes in your Laravel application.
php artisan r:l
If your route is not registered, it might be due to cached data. To clear the cache, run the following command: php artisan optimize:clear .
This will clear any cached data and ensure that your routes are up-to-date.
Check this link about clear cache:
In my case this will work perfectly.

The problem might not be in your routing, you are not finding any task so the service return a 404, as pointed by @geertjanknapen:
public function changeStatus(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $task = Task::find($id);
            if (!$task) {
                //This is what you need to debug
                return Helper::error(__('messages.task_not_found'), 404);
            }
...
        

